# Query in writing the test case validations in selenium webdriver using TestNg

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-ide

I am doing the Automation testing for the web-app made of angular using selenium webdriver with test Ng.In that i find some difficulties in switching between the various views in the web-app.

Suggest me some ideas to switch between the multiple views selenium webdriver using TestNg.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use protractor to write test for angularJS apps.

Comment: Why then what is the difference between the testNg and Protractor.

Comment: TestNG is a testing framework;
Protractor is an end-to-end test framework for AngularJS applications